# Select com LIKE e POST

Tags: php, mysql

Olá

Eu estou tentando utilizar um LIKE em um SELECT, os dados viram via GET, mas não funciona, oque pode estar errado ?

```
$nome = $_GET['nome'];

$row=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome'%");
```

Obrigado

Comment: Já tentou colocar o ultimo % dentro das aspas simples?

Comment: Agora deu certo. Obrigado KillerJack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo tenta usar um filtro no `GET` para evitar inject.

Tenta assim:

```
$nome = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));

$row=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome%'"); // Primeiro o %, depois a aspa simples
```

Para facilitar, posta o erro que esta retornando no seu php.

Comment: Olá amigo. Não tem erro algum na tela nem no console do Google Chrome

Comment: Bom vc esta usando o metodo `GET` certo. Com ele vc tem que passar o nome pela URL, se for usar um formulário vc tem que usar o método `POST`.

Comment: Olá Hugo. Obrigado, mas já esta resolvido.

Comment: Posta como resolveu o problema, pois isso pode ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: +1 pelo escape dos caracteres especiais. A molecada tem que aprender isso desde cedo pra ficar no sangue.

Comment: Eu resolvi o problema, seguindo o conselho do KillerJack, alterei a posição das aspas simples.